# Use two database in one mysql sql query

Tags: mysql

I want to use 2 database in one sql query.I will run query in one db and another db should get selected by prefixing db name to table but the second DB name i want to select dynamically.
Eg:

```
SELECT * FROM db1.contact WHERE id 
IN (SELECT contact_id FROM (REPLACE(DATABASE(),1,2)).email);
```

How i can do this?

Comment: Clarify dynamically?, the **REPLACE** you are using there is a **STRING** handling function, it cannot be used on **DATABASE()**, which is a server/session setting.

Comment: You can't do it. You must use 2 queries.

Comment: Why do you have so many databases?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM db1.contact WHERE id IN (SELECT contact_id FROM db2.email);
```

And for the second server:

```
SELECT * FROM db21.contact WHERE id IN (SELECT contact_id FROM db1.email);
```

But cannot dynamically chose the database, as the **DATABASE** portion of the SQL doesn't support any type of **Functions** (Such as REPLACE, IF, etc)

Comment: I have around 50 db pair like,

Comment: I have around 50 db pair like,

ae_db_1,ae_db_2
ca_db_1,ca_db_2
de_db_1,de_db_2
...............and so on
I have script to select all db_1 one by one and run the above sql query.In that query i need to select db_2 query dynamically.
eg: My script will select ae_db_1 and run the query now ae_db_2 should get selected dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see to do it is dynamic SQL;

```
SELECT @dbname := 'db2';
SELECT @query := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM db1.contact WHERE id IN ',
                        '(SELECT contact_id FROM ', @dbname, '.email);');

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```